# whereBetween not working with Carbon::parse()->subDay() & current day laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i want to query whereBetween two dates with time

here is code which is working fine

```
whereBetween('created_at', [now()->subDay()->format('Y-m-d') . ' ' . $tgame->start_time->format('H:i:s'), now()->format('Y-m-d') . ' ' . $tgame->end_time->format('H:i:s')]
```

but this code is not working

```
$date = Carbon::parse($request->date);
whereBetween('created_at', [$date->subDay()->format('Y-m-d') . ' ' . $tgame->start_time->format('H:i:s'), $date->format('Y-m-d') . ' ' . $tgame->end_time->format('H:i:s')]
```

please also explain thank you

Comment: `$request->date` and `now()` could be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `subDay()` on the `$date` object will set the time in the Carbon object back 24 hours. So in the upper boundary for `whereBetween`, you are not using the request date, but the one 24 hours back.

To achieve what you want, you need to copy the object before changing it:

```
...->whereBetween('created_at', [$date->copy()->subDay()->format('Y-m-d') . ' ' . $tgame->start_time->format('H:i:s'), $date->format('Y-m-d') . ' ' . $tgame->end_time->format('H:i:s')]
```